# "Ready for sale" App not showing on appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

My app is showing as ready for sale but I can see my app online through the URL. When I search with the app name it doesn't show in the result, though I am able to search my app by my company name on the app store.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Have you tried sending out an update? I had this issue a week or so ago, and I resolved it by just pushing an update where the only change was the version number.

Comment: Yes, I have updated my app multiple times. I think the issue is related app name and keyword. The search work with [appname + any keyword from our ASO] but doesn't with the only app name. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You need to either get more ratings/reviews, or choose keywords that are less popular so your app can rank for them.

Answer (score 0):

usually it took 1-4 hours to Appstore update version or add app initially

Comment: It's been almost 6 months. I called them, had a chat with app store team and sent multiple mails but no solution.